# Changing the position of the editor with biblatex (@inbook)

Tags: biblatex

I'd like my citations to become the following:

> Kline, Michael; Nilsen, Micheline: Paris Commune, 1871. In: Ness,
>   Immanuel; Herz, Jonah (Hgg.): The International Encyclopedia of
>   Revolution and Protest. 1500 to the Present, Bd. 5. Chichester 2009: 2610-2613.

At the moment it looks like this:

> Kline, Michael; Nilsen, Micheline: Paris Commune, 1871. In: The
>   International Encyclopedia of Revolution and Protest. 1500 to the
>   Present. Ness, Immanuel; Herz, Jonah (Hgg.). Bd. 5. Chichester 2009,
>   2610-2613.

So three things to change:

1. Most importantly, the editors (Hg./Hgg.) have to be between the 'In:' and the Title of the book.
2. between the year and the page there should be a colon and not a comma
3. Before the Volume (Bd. 5) I'd like to have a comma and no point.

Is there a possibility to do this in my preamble?

If got the following stuff going on for my bibliography:

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@inbook{Kline:Commune,
        author = {Kline, Michael and Nilsen, Micheline},
        title = {Paris Commune, 1871},
        editor = {Ness, Immanuel and Herz, Jonah},
        booktitle = {The International Encyclopedia of Revolution and Protest},
        booksubtitle = {1500 to the Present},
        volume = {5},
        pages = {2610--2613},
        date = {2009},
        location = {Chichester},
        }
\end{filecontents}



\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrreprt} %Inhaltsverzeichnis andere Schrift.. bei report normal
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%=============BIBLIOGRAPHIE, ZITIERWEISE=================== %
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
style=alphabetic,
style=verbose-ibid,
labeldate,
dashed=false, %bei mehreren Werken desselben Autors kein Strich
backend=bibtex8,
idemtracker=false,
ibidtracker=constrict,
]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{% %Hg. bzw Hgg. in Klammern hinter Herausgeber, statt davor
        \ifnameundef{editor}
        {}
        {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
                \setunit{\addspace}%
                \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
                \clearname{editor}%
                \newunit}%
        \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
        \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
        andothers = {et\ al\adddot}, %et al. statt u.a.
        editor = {\mkbibparens{Hg\adddot}}, %Hg. statt Hrsg.
        editors = {\mkbibparens{Hgg\adddot}}, %Hgg. plural
        byeditor = {\mkbibparens {Hg\adddot}},
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1} %unterdrückt Präfix S.
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1} %unterdrückt Präfix S.
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first} %Autoren immer Nachname, Vorname sortieren
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
        \printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit*{\nameyeardelim}%
        \iffieldundef{labelyear}
        {}
        {\printtext[\addcolon]{\printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
                                \printfield{labelyear}%
                                \printfield{extrayear}}}}}
%\DeclareNameFormat{default}{%
%\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
%\usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space} %Semikolon zum trennen der Autoren
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} %Zwischen Autor und Titel Doppelpunkt, kein Punkt
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space} %Zwischen Jahrzahl und Seitenzahl Doppelpunkt, kein Komma
\renewcommand{\nametitledelim}{\addspace}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{% %Zwischen Ort und Jahr kein Komma
        \printlist{location}%
        {\setunit*{\addspace}}
        \usebibmacro{date}%
        \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{#1} %Titel nicht in Anführungszeichen
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{pages}{#1}% S. vor Seitenangabe entfernen
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} %Titel nicht in Anführungszeichen
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}% S. vor Seitenangabe entfernen

%\renewcommand{\nametitledelim}{\space}

\bibliography{test} %name des .bib-Files

% Titel nicht schräg
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{#1}

% Journal Titel nicht schräg
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}

%=============ENDE BIBLIOGRAPHIE, ZITIERWEISE=================== %
\begin{document}
Test\footcite{Kline:Commune}
\end{document}
```

So can anyone help me? That'd be great :)

Here the way it looks atm:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A screenshot of example bibliography would be nice in order to make it easier to understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Are you sure about `inbook` instead of `incollection`? According to the biblatex manual a `collection` is a book with multiple, self-contained contributions by distinct authors which have their own title.  (Anyway it  does not change  the question).

Comment: Hmmm.. I actually tried incollection first, but inbook looked more the way I liked it..

Comment: Well, I just tried incolection now and it looks the same. Maybe you're right :)

Comment: `inreference` might be even better (though I think it will just alias `incollection` for the standard styles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `xpatch` package and its `\xpatchbibdriver` command. If you want use the incollection entry type, you should patch the ìncollection` bib driver in an analog way.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrreprt} %Inhaltsverzeichnis andere Schrift.. bei report normal
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@inbook{Kline:Commune,
        author = {Kline, Michael and Nilsen, Micheline},
        title = {Paris Commune, 1871},
        editor = {Ness, Immanuel and Herz, Jonah},
        booktitle = {The International Encyclopedia of Revolution and Protest},
        booksubtitle = {1500 to the Present},
        volume = {5},
        pages = {2610--2613},
        date = {2009},
        location = {Chichester},
        }
\end{filecontents}

%=============BIBLIOGRAPHIE, ZITIERWEISE=================== %
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
style=alphabetic,
style=verbose-ibid,
labeldate,
dashed=false, %bei mehreren Werken desselben Autors kein Strich
backend=biber, %bibtex8,
idemtracker=false,
ibidtracker=constrict,
]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{% %Hg. bzw Hgg. in Klammern hinter Herausgeber, statt davor
 \ifnameundef{editor}
 {}
 {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
 \setunit{\addspace}%
 \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
 \clearname{editor}%
 \newunit}%
 \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
 \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
 andothers = {et\ al\adddot}, %et al. statt u.a.
 editor = {\mkbibparens{Hg\adddot}}, %Hg. statt Hrsg.
 editors = {\mkbibparens{Hgg\adddot}}, %Hgg. plural
 byeditor = {\mkbibparens {Hg\adddot}},
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1} %unterdrückt Präfix S.
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1} %unterdrückt Präfix S.
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first} %Autoren immer Nachname, Vorname sortieren
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
 \printnames{labelname}%
 \setunit*{\nameyeardelim}%
 \iffieldundef{labelyear}
 {}
 {\printtext[\addcolon]{\printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
 \printfield{labelyear}%
 \printfield{extrayear}}}}}
%\DeclareNameFormat{default}{%
%\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
%\usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space} %Semikolon zum trennen der Autoren
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} %Zwischen Autor und Titel Doppelpunkt, kein Punkt
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space} %Zwischen Jahrzahl und Seitenzahl Doppelpunkt, kein Komma
\renewcommand{\nametitledelim}{\addspace}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{% %Zwischen Ort und Jahr kein Komma
 \printlist{location}%
 {\setunit*{\addspace}}
 \usebibmacro{date}%
 \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{#1} %Titel nicht in Anführungszeichen
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{pages}{#1}% S. vor Seitenangabe entfernen
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} %Titel nicht in Anführungszeichen
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}% S. vor Seitenangabe entfernen

%%\renewcommand{\nametitledelim}{\space}

\addbibresource{test.bib} %name des .bib-Files

% Titel nicht schräg
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{#1}

% Journal Titel nicht schräg
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
}%
  {%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  }%
  {}{}%

\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}{%
 \newunit\newblock
 \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
}%
{%
\addcolon\space
 \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
}%
{}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}{%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
}%
{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
}%
{}{}
%=============ENDE BIBLIOGRAPHIE, ZITIERWEISE=================== %
\begin{document}
Test\footcite{Kline:Commune}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This redefines the `@incollection` formatting. It only addresses points 1 and 2 because, unlike Bernard, I wasn't confident enough to address 3. (I'm worried my solution will have unwanted side-effects in other entries.)

Bernard's is probably better but I'd already worked this out so I'm posting anyway:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Kline:Commune,
        author = {Kline, Michael and Nilsen, Micheline},
        title = {Paris Commune, 1871},
        editor = {Ness, Immanuel and Herz, Jonah},
        booktitle = {The International Encyclopedia of Revolution and Protest},
        booksubtitle = {1500 to the Present},
        volume = {5},
        pages = {2610--2613},
        date = {2009},
        location = {Chichester},
        }
\end{filecontents}



\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrreprt} %Inhaltsverzeichnis andere Schrift.. bei report normal
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  style=alphabetic,
  style=verbose-ibid,
  labeldate,
  dashed=false, %bei mehreren Werken desselben Autors kein Strich
  backend=bibtex8,
  idemtracker=false,
  ibidtracker=constrict,
  ]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{% %Hg. bzw Hgg. in Klammern hinter Herausgeber, statt davor
        \ifnameundef{editor}
        {}
        {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
                \setunit{\addspace}%
                \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
                \clearname{editor}%
                \newunit}%
        \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
        \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
        andothers = {et\ al\adddot}, %et al. statt u.a.
        editor = {\mkbibparens{Hg\adddot}}, %Hg. statt Hrsg.
        editors = {\mkbibparens{Hgg\adddot}}, %Hgg. plural
        byeditor = {\mkbibparens {Hg\adddot}},
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1} %unterdrückt Präfix S.
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1} %unterdrückt Präfix S.
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first} %Autoren immer Nachname, Vorname sortieren
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
        \printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit*{\nameyeardelim}%
        \iffieldundef{labelyear}
        {}
        {\printtext[\addcolon]{\printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
                                \printfield{labelyear}%
                                \printfield{extrayear}}}}}
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space} %Semikolon zum trennen der Autoren
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} %Zwischen Autor und Titel Doppelpunkt, kein Punkt
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space} %Zwischen Jahrzahl und Seitenzahl Doppelpunkt, kein Komma
\renewcommand{\nametitledelim}{\addspace}
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{% %Zwischen Ort und Jahr kein Komma
        \printlist{location}%
        {\setunit*{\addspace}}
        \usebibmacro{date}%
        \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1} %Titel nicht in Anführungszeichen
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{pages}{#1}% S. vor Seitenangabe entfernen

\bibliography{\jobname} %name des .bib-Files

\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{#1}


\begin{document}
Test\footcite{Kline:Commune}

\fullcite{Kline:Commune}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```